# real time vim keylogger

Tags: bash

is there anyway to log vim keypresses (or keypresses in general activated by vim) and record it somewhere (STDOUT, file, etc) in real time? I want somthing similar to `vim -w file.log file` and [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4634/how-to-record-my-keyboard-input-to-do-statistics-on-it), but in real-time (within 5 seconds updates) and without saving the file.