# How does vimgolf record all keystrokes?

Tags: key-bindings, user-input

From time to time I like to engage in a round of [vimgolf](http://vimgolf.com/). It can be enlightening.

How are they able to record all the keystrokes? That must be a vim feature. Anybody any idea how to do that. It could come in handy to record everything in certain circumstances.

Comment: I just found out that we have a pretty similar question [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4634/1841)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They probably use the built-in parameter `-w`, see [`:h -w`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#-w):

```
-w {scriptout}  All the characters that you type are recorded in the file
        "scriptout", until you exit Vim.  This is useful if you want
        to create a script file to be used with "vim -s" or
        ":source!".  When the "scriptout" file already exists, new
        characters are appended.  See also |complex-repeat|.
        {scriptout} cannot start with a digit.
        {not in Vi}
```

*Edit* As @B Layer pointed out the actual code uses the `-W` parameter which is basically the same as `-w` but the log file is overwritten instead of appending the keystrokes to it ([`:h -W`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#-W)):

```
-W {scriptout}  Like -w, but do not append, overwrite an existing file.
        {not in Vi}
```

Comment: Good guess! It's `-W` not `-w` (see my answer) but still...

Comment: @BLayer Well played I was too lazy to look at their code :-) I'll update with the doc for `-W` which is basically the same.

Comment: Yep. Just append vs write.

Comment: A (good) guess outvotes and gets accepted over a well-researched, fact-based answer? A grave injustice has been done. :(   ... _LOL_

Comment: @BLayer Ahah at least you have my upvote because I always upvote an answer based on a research in a source code :)

Comment: 'Tis a noble gesture. I humbly accept your vote, good sir or madam. Dilly dilly.

Answer (score 16):

I don't think it's quite that simple but you can look at the Ruby code yourself here:

https://github.com/igrigorik/vimgolf/tree/master/lib/vimgolf

I see a class for keylogging, for one.

Here's the command that is used to launch `vim` in [lib/vimgolf/cli.rb](https://github.com/igrigorik/vimgolf/blob/master/lib/vimgolf/lib/vimgolf/cli.rb):

```
 vimcmd = GOLFVIM.shellsplit + %W{-Z -n --noplugin --nofork -i NONE +0 
    -u #{challenge.vimrc_path} -U NONE -W #{challenge.log_path} #{challenge.work_path}}
```

@statox was (very nearly) right about `-w outfile` ... `-W outfile`, actually, which overwrites the file to which the typed characters are sent rather than appending to it. But as I said, not "quite that simple"...compare the contents of one of those files and what gets generated by the vimgolf tool. This is from [an actual vimgolf problem](http://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/4d716c76919202611400002b)...

**`-W` output:**

```
^VGI0. ^[gvg^AZZ
```

**vimgolf displayed/uploaded output:**

```
<C-V>GI0. <Esc>gvg<C-A>ZZ
```

---

**Update:** I spent a few minutes looking a bit closer at things. Here's how the raw form gets converted to the more readable Vimgolf format...

[The keylogger class keylog.rb](https://github.com/igrigorik/vimgolf/blob/master/lib/vimgolf/lib/vimgolf/keylog.rb) that I mention above is indeed a major piece of the puzzle but it's actually fairly straightforward. The keycodes that Vim saves to the `-W` log file are either one byte or three bytes long. The latter always start with the value 0x80 to distinguish them from one-byte codes.

To decode the one-byte keycodes a simple array lookup is done.

Example: If you press <kbd>G</kbd> the byte 0x47 is saved to the `-W` file. (Hex 47 is the ASCII code for the letter `G`.) In the lookup array the element at position 0x47 contains, naturally, `G`. For printable characters this is an obvious conversion but it's necessary for non-printable ASCII characters that we want to have a nice name like `<Esc>` and `<CR>`.

For multi-byte keycodes there is a hash table that maps bytes two and three to a human readable string.

Example: If you press <kbd>Home</kbd> the three-byte sequence `80 6B 68` is saved to the `-W` file. The last two bytes are converted to ASCII and concatenated: `kh`. In the hash table that string is mapped to the string `<Home>`.

There are some exceptions/corner-cases that are handled differently but most of the keycodes are resolved by one of the two methods described above.