# Should the output of the -w {scriptout} flag work to replay actions using the -s {scriptin} flag?

Tags: repeated-commands

According to the `:help startup-options`, this is `-w`'s behviour

```
-w {scriptout}  All the characters that you type are recorded in the file
                "scriptout", until you exit Vim.  This is useful if you want
                to create a script file to be used with "vim -s" or
                ":source!".
```

Specifically, it mentions the `-s` flag as a useful application of `-w`'s output.

Testing this, it seems there isn't a 1-1 mapping of the two flags.

For all standard keycodes, `-s` behaves as expected when running `-w`'s output.

However, when "special" keycodes are used when running with `-w` (e.g. `<Del>`, `<Up>`, ...), Vim will output a special abstraction of these keycodes, that according to the documentation is a terminal-independent representation - for example, `<Del>` is written in `-w`'s output as `<80><6b><44> (hexa)` (`<80>kD`).

I expected Vim's behaviour to interpret the above sequence (`<80><6b><44>`) as `<Del>` when it is part of `-s`'s input, but that is not the case. It appears to do something different which I have not been able to fully decipher yet.

Am I trying to use `-s` in ways that are not intended? Or perhaps there is some hidden Vim option to make this work? Or is it simply a bug in Vim?

Any input will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

### Update

Some details I gathered:

- `<80>` is interpreted as a literal `<80>` through `-s`, which ends up as `<80><fe>X`. I don't think this is the intended behaviour.
- The suggestion to use `execute 'normal!'` ended up not being suited for my use case as macros are disabled when running through `normal`.

My use case actually required "replaying" user input for a fork of a python implementation of the vimgolf client :) (https://github.com/dankilman/vimgolf).

I ended up using `feedkeys("<key sequence>", 't')` which met all my requirements.

Comment: Interesting. Meanwhile the [Vim Golf client app actually prettifies `-w` output](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14441/how-does-vimgolf-record-all-keystrokes/14443#14443) so you'll get `<Del>`. I wonder if putting _that_ through `vim -s` would result in expected behavior.

Comment: Note also the fact that the Vimgolf client has to do the prettying surely indicates that there's no way to get such a result from Vim natively.

Comment: Thanks for the link @BLayer. Putting `<Del>` through `-s` will actually interpret it as the actual keys: `<`, `D`, `e`, `l`, `>` :)

Comment: Well, that's no good. I guess it will come as no surprise that I've used `-s` exactly zero times in my life. :D I was thinking it parsed along the lines of mapping and/or expression parser. :P

Comment: `I expected Vim's behaviour to interpret the above sequence (<80><6b><44>) as <Del>` Looks like `source!` fully expects only text input. But note that this seems to work okay: `:execute 'normal!' readfile('scriptout', 'b')[0]`

Comment: @Matt it does! Interesting. Using `-s` directly would have been cleaner for my use case, but this solution works perfectly! Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug registered on [March 17th,
2019](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/26967617a30e55aedc98b8f14b841d88469abd0e#diff-38d7929bd26d74d92ceddf984bbfc8dbR164-R173)
and reported on [February 24th, 2019](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/4041). From [`:help known-bugs`](https://vimhelp.org/todo.txt.html#known-bugs):

```
Bug: script written with "-W scriptout" contains Key codes, while the script
read with "-s scriptin" expects escape codes.  Probably "scriptout" needs to
be adjusted. (Daniel Steinberg, 2019 Feb 24, #4041)
```

As of this writing, it doesn't have a priority classification so it might take
a while before we get a fix for it. A similar issue reported on [October 20th,
2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3981535/1121933) (and related issue on [March 4th,
2013](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/vim_dev/bUByeZXCetk/discussion)) suggests this bug is in place (at least) since then.

Comment: An interesting anecdote is that the person that filed this bug is the same person with the initial python vimgolf client implementation which I based my fork on :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. What a small world we live in.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a nasty bug.

When writing a script out, Vim uses its "<>-notation" for keycodes, i.e. `"\<BS>"` (`<80>kb`) for backspace key, `"\<del>"` (`<80>kD`) for delete key, etc.

However, they only get converted back into "real" keys if pumped through `:normal`. While `-s` or `:source!` simply allow them to pass through!

It's also interesting to note that Neovim seems to suffer from the same problem, except "backspace" key, as it gets written out as `<8>`, so it eventually works. But `"\<del>"` and others are just the same as in Vim.

So as a workaround you can do the following: `:execute 'normal!' readfile('scriptout', 'b')[0]` Otherwise, I believe, it should be reported as a bug.

Comment: It should be noted that using this (`:execute 'normal!'`) method, if `scriptout` included any recording of macros, they will not be recorded when replayed.

Comment: @dankilman `q` does not work in `:normal`, as it's mentioned in `:h q`. And also all other limitations would apply, such as "can't stay in insert mode", "can't `gQ` to ex-mode" etc.