# Is there a plugin to show (maybe in the status line) the (unprocessed) keystrokes?

Tags: plugin

To understand what I'm referring about, think of [screenkey](https://youtu.be/1T9w9cTH0eA).

As for why I'd like such a plugin, [here](https://github.com/Aster89/WinZoZ)'s a plugin of mine (well, my only plugin so far). As you can see there's a screencast to show the usage. So I basically recorded a GIF of the screen while I was using my plugin with *screenkey* in execution.

But what if, instead of GIF (or video), I want to use [`asciinema`](https://asciinema.org/)? For that to work, the keys I press must be show *inside* the very same terminal that's being recorded.

Hence my question/curiosity.

I thought for a moment I could try to implement such a plugin myself, but the moment after that I realized I have no idea how to catch keystrokes. It looks like I'd need to wrap Vim in an other executable which sees all the keystrokes flow and forwards them to Vim both as keystrokes and as string representing them, the latter needed for Vim to have something that can be `echo`ed in the status line or anywhere else.

(Oh, please, let's add some tag on this site. I have no idea how to tag this question.)

Comment: Does `set showcmd` do enough for you?   If you type `dG` for example, to delete until the end of the file, the `d` will show up on the right side of the statusline, but will disappear when you hit `G`

Comment: @ChrisHeithoff no, I'm looking for a solution that shows all the keys as they are hit, just like the non-terminal program screenkey that I linked.

Comment: Probably no good, easy options here. If you're _extremely_ committed you could try modifying the code for Vim's `-w {filename}` flag, [used by Vimgolf](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14441), so it flushes typed characters immediately and submit a patch. :)

Comment: @BLayer, thanks, that's really a good info. When you say _flushes typed characters immediately_ you mean in contrast to now that it flushes the characters only when one exits Vim? In that case you're approach would be that the plugin would as "was vim opened with `-w filename`? Keep reading that file and take action to show the last whatever chars in it. Else do nothing", have I understood?

Comment: @Enlico Yeah, that's pretty much what I envisioned as the path of least resistance. However, if I were in there modifying code to do the quick flush I'd also probably look at how much effort it would take to do something even fancier like redirect the characters to an internal variable or buffer or whatever.